# Get Blob URL from Azure Get-AzStorageContainer where Public Access is set to On?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to get the URL for all of my Blob in all Storage accounts and all Resource groups.

The command below can be used, but I need to iterate through all objects in all of my current subscription.

```
# Set variables.
$rgName = "<resource-group>"
$accountName = "<storage-account>"
$containerName = "<container>"

# Get context object.
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $accountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

# Read the container's public access setting.
Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Context $ctx
```

Script parameters removed like below:

```
# Get context object.
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

# Read the container's public access setting.
Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Context $ctx
```

However, the error is:

```
Get-AzStorageContainer : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext' required by parameter 'Context'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:6 char:36
+ Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Context $ctx
+                                    ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzStorageContainer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageContainerCommand

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>  $ctx[0].GetType().FullName
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.LazyAzureStorageContext
```

The suggested method by Kryzstof:

```
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount
$ctxs = $storageAccount.Context

&{
     foreach ($ctx in $ctxs) {
        $acl = Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Context $ctx
        Write-Host $acl
     }
} | ogv
```

is showing some strange result like below:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.Resourc
> eModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Co
> mmands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.Resourc
> eModel.AzureStorageContainer
>
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.Resourc
> eModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Co
> mmands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContai
> ner
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.Resourc
> eModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Co
> mmands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContai
> ner
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.Res
> ourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzur
> e.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageCo
> ntainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage
> .ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.Windows
> Azure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStora
> geContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Sto
> rage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer

Comment: Judging on the error message, `$ctx` is an array. Can you do a `$ctx[0].GetType().FullName` ?

Comment: @Theo, I've updated the code as above:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>  $ctx[0].GetType().FullName
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.LazyAzureStorageContext

Comment: @Theo, the updated result is as per the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have array and you can't pass it at once. You'll have to call it for each available context:

```bsh
# Get context object.
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount #-ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $accountName
$ctxs = $storageAccount.Context

 foreach ($ctx in $ctxs) {
    # Read the container's public access setting.
    $acl = Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Context $ctx

    Write-Host $acl

 }
```

Please try use just '$acl | Out-GridView' (instead of `Write-Host $acl`) and you should get:

[image]

If you want to get just URI you can get it from here
`Write-Host $acl.Context.BlobEndPoint` however if this is not exactly what you want please call `$acl| ConvertTo-JSON` and find property you are looking for.

Comment: @Krzystof, thank you for the response. How can I Output the result into OGV?

Comment: Can you explain what OGV mean?

Comment: Out-Gridview, instead of export-csv

Comment: Did you try`| Out-GridView`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7

Comment: Do you still have the issue?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer did you see my update? Does it solve your issue?

Comment: @Krzystof, yes, finally it works great as expected, thanks man !

Comment: Would it be possible to show only the Publicly Accessible URI?